# differences between PFType0Font and PFType1Font file sizes

Tags: pdfbox

I've started to use PDType0Font instead of PDType1Font (due to IllegalArgumentException) and noticed that my pdf files that are being generated have ~double size now (from 1.5MB it jumped to 2.8MB and from 19KB jumped to 298KB).
I also noticed that it is directly related to the number of fields in the form that I need to fill with data.

Is it the expected behavior? If so, is there a 'best practice' way to use PFType0Font? Is there a way to optimize it?

UPDATE: I've changed my code to prevent subsetting.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use a parameter to prevent subsetting? (uh, probably yes, it is needed for a form field) Can you share the "before" and "after" PDF?

Comment: I remember that there was a similar question some time ago, but I'm sortof tired... I think the trick was to save the file first, and then set the values, to prevent duplication of the fonts.

Comment: *"Is there a way to optimize it?"* - that is difficult to say; you don't show what you do now, so how should we be able to tell how to do it better?

Comment: @mkl, for each document i'm running loadFont(document) with these parameters: (PDType0Font.load(document, FontLoader.fontTtf, true), then for each field in document.documentCatalog.acroForm.fields object I'm filling the field with the correct data.

Comment: Please try what I mentioned, i.e. first assign the font to the default resources and set the /DA in the fields, save, close, reload, and then fill the fields, save, close.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - do you mean to do the following when I'm loading a file to PDDocument? 
PDDocument.load(file).use { document ->
      val pdfFont = AcroFormHandler.loadFont(document)
     document.documentCatalog.acroForm.getDefaultResources().put(MYFONT)?
Also, what do you mean by "set the /DA in the fields"?

Comment: I don't know what AcroFormHandler is doing. Typically, if you want to change the field font, you do `String fontName = defaultResources.add(formFont).getName();` and use that fontName for the `field.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g")` call. See the CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java example.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr sorry for being unclear. this is my code to load the font:
`val pdfFont = PDType0Font.load(document, TTFParser().parse(AcroFormHandler::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("fonts/arial.ttf")), false)`

And then:
`document.documentCatalog.acroForm.defaultResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"), pdfFont)`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 

and for each field text that I want to insert, i'm doing:
`val pdfFont: PDFont = acroForm.defaultResources.getFont(COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"))`
to retrieve the font from default resources and then:
`contentStream.beginText()
    contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize)
....
    contentStream.endText()
    contentStream.close()`
Do you suggest to do it in a different way?

Comment: To set a field, just call field.setValue(), unless you are doing the appearance stream yourself. (Which would be very advanced) You should really read the examples in the source code download.